# Splitting 1 column's value into 3 separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT  
    Item.item,
    (CASE 
        WHEN item.item LIKE 'RC-%' THEN 'Rectangle'
        WHEN item.item LIKE 'T-%' THEN 'PIPE'
        WHEN item.item LIKE 'B-%' THEN 'BAR'
     END) as PROD_TYPE
FROM 
    item
WHERE 
    item.item LIKE 'RC-%' OR 
    item.item LIKE 'T-%' OR 
    item.item LIKE 'B-%'
```

That produces this dataset:

```
item            PROD_TYPE
=========================
B-10.000-XM12   BAR
B-1045-10.000   BAR
B-1045-10.500   BAR
B-1045-12.000   BAR
```

I need to split the item column into 3 separate columns so it looks like this:

```
item            PROD_TYPE   col1  col2       col3
===================================================
B-10.000-XM12   BAR         B     10.000     XM12
B-1045-10.000   BAR         B     1045       10.000
B-1045-10.500   BAR         B     1045       10.500
B-1045-12.000   BAR         B     1045       12.000
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT  
    Item.item,
    SUBSTRING (Item.item, 1, CHARINDEX('-', Item.item) - 1) col1,
    SUBSTRING (Item.item, CHARINDEX ('-', Item.item) + 1, LEN(Item.item)) col2,
    REVERSE (PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(REPLACE(Item.item,'.','/')), '-', '.'), 3)) as col3,
    (CASE 
        WHEN item.item LIKE 'RC-%' THEN 'Rectangle'
        WHEN item.item LIKE 'T-%' THEN 'PIPE'
        WHEN item.item LIKE 'B-%' THEN 'BAR'
     END) as PROD_TYPE
FROM 
    item
WHERE 
    item.item LIKE 'RC-%' OR 
    item.item LIKE 'T-%' OR 
    item.item LIKE 'B-%'
```

and that query returns this result:

```
item            col1   col2         col3    PRO_TYPE
----------------------------------------------------
B-10.000-XM12   B      10.000-XM12  XM12    BAR
B-1045-10.000   B      1045-10.000  10/000  BAR
B-1045-10.500   B      1045-10.500  10/500  BAR
```

I simply can't figure out how to get the next index of the dash for the final part in the item data.

thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at this link multiple options provided https://datamajor.net/mssqlsplitcolumn/

Comment: `case when charindex('.', col) > charindex('-', col, 3) then ... else ... end`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has lousy string splitting functionality (hint, hint:  the database is not the best place for these transformations).

I find that `cross apply` with string functions is the best way to approach these problems:

```
with items as (
      select 'B-10.000-XM12' as item union all
      select 'B-1045-10.000' as item union all
      select 'B-1045-10.500' as item union all
      select 'B-1045-12.000' as item 
     )
select *,
       (CASE WHEN i.item LIKE 'RC-%' THEN 'Rectangle'
             WHEN i.item LIKE 'T-%' THEN 'PIPE'
             WHEN i.item LIKE 'B-%' THEN 'BAR'
        END) as PROD_TYPE,
       v1.col, v2.col, v2.rest
from items i cross apply
     (values (left(i.item, charindex('-', i.item) - 1),
              stuff(i.item, 1, charindex('-', i.item), ''))
     ) v1(col, rest) cross apply
     (values (left(v1.rest, charindex('-', v1.rest) - 1),
              stuff(v1.rest, 1, charindex('-', v1.rest), ''))
     ) v2(col, rest);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=429ff6788a6c172b77b07f34936883e0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([item] varchar(50),[PROD_TYPE] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('B-10.000-XM12','BAR')
,('B-1045-10.000','BAR')
,('B-1045-10.500','BAR')
,('B-1045-12.000','BAR')
 
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace([item],'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) A(xDim) 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
item            PROD_TYPE   Pos1    Pos2    Pos3
B-10.000-XM12   BAR         B       10.000  XM12
B-1045-10.000   BAR         B       1045    10.000
B-1045-10.500   BAR         B       1045    10.500
B-1045-12.000   BAR         B       1045    12.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross apply makes expression nesting look nice and neat:

```
select      Item.item,
            prod_type = case 
                            WHEN item.item like 'RC-%' THEN 'Rectangle'
                            WHEN item.item like 'T-%' THEN 'PIPE'
                            WHEN item.item like 'B-%' THEN 'BAR'
                        end,
            col1      = left(item, h1.pos - 1),
            col2      = substring(item, h1.pos + 1, h2.pos - h1.pos - 1),
            col3      = right(item, len(item) - h2.pos)

from        item
cross apply (select charindex('-', item)) h1(pos)
cross apply (select charindex('-', item, h1.pos + 1)) h2(pos)
where       item.item like 'RC-%' 
or          item.item LIKE 'T-%' 
or          item.item LIKE 'B-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options are listed in other answers - As I commented before - The detailed explanation of your scenarios is listed in this https://datamajor.net/mssqlsplitcolumn/

Already couple of options are posted as answer listing the left out ones as well -

```
create Table tabl ([item] varchar(50),[PROD_TYPE] varchar(50));
Insert Into tabl Values 
 ('B-10.000-XM12','BAR')
,('B-1045-10.000','BAR')
,('B-1045-10.500','BAR')
,('B-1045-12.000','BAR');
```

Method 1. String_Split

```
WITH C AS(
SELECT ITEM
      ,value 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM tabl BO
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ITEM, '-') AS BK
)
SELECT ITEM
      ,[1] AS COL1
      ,[2] AS COl2
      ,[3] AS COL3
FROM C
PIVOT(
    MAX(VALUE)
    FOR RN IN([1],[2],[3])  
) as PVT ;
```

***Using Functions***

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetColumnValue(
    @String VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter CHAR(1),
    @Column INT = 1
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS    
BEGIN
DECLARE @idx INT
DECLARE @slice VARChar(MAX)     
SELECT @idx = 1     
    IF LEN(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL
        RETURN NULL
DECLARE @ColCnt INT
    SET @ColCnt = 1
WHILE (@idx != 0)
BEGIN    
    SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)     
    IF @idx!=0 
    BEGIN
        IF (@ColCnt = @Column) 
            RETURN LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)        
        SET @ColCnt = @ColCnt + 1
    END
    SET @String = RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String) - @idx)     
    IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN @String  
END 
;

SELECT
    ITEM ,
    dbo.GetColumnValue(ITEM, '-', 1) as PRODUCTID 
        ,dbo.GetColumnValue(ITEM, '-', 2) as NAME
        ,dbo.GetColumnValue(ITEM, '-', 3) as PAGES

FROM TABL
```